# Google Calendar API reader permissions only

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Application fetches calendar list and checks if user can read or write to that calendar. This is the API call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/
```

For that purpose I created new user and gave him Super Admin privileges that should have read and write permissions to all calendars.

In the response I'm looking for accessRole tag. For super admin this should be 'writer' but I'm getting only 'reader'. What could be the issue? Could it be that it takes some time when super admin privileges reflect on a user and API calls?

With other super user admin that has been created couple of months ago there is no such issue. It gets writer accessRole to all calendars.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you grant this user super admin privileges to all calendars?

Comment: In the google admin console I gave this user Super Admin rights. Like mentioned here https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to do it per calendar in Google Calendar but I cant test Google APPs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that it didn't pass 24 hours after user credentials change to Super Admin.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6067607?hl=en